# What programs emit C++ code and pass it to mainstream compilers?

Tags: c++, compiler

I suspect there're programs that instead of emitting machine code instead emit C++ code and then start a mainstream C++ compiler to compile it to machine code.

I can't find any notable examples except MIDL which emits some rather primitive code.

What are notable examples of such systems?

Comment: Most new languages go through a phase of emitting C code (before they get their own backend). Mainly this is because C compilers are nearly ubiquitous across all platforms and quite efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**HipHop from Facebook**](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php) transforms PHP code into C++.

Answer (score 3):

The [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_%28programming_language%29) compiler in [EiffelStudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EiffelStudio) compiles to C (maybe with some C++ in it). One reason why it takes **ages** to compile even the simples Eiffel programs.

The Haskell compiler [GHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler) used to target a C-like language [C--](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C--). Today, it generates machine code directly. A backend targetting [LLVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) also exists.

Comment: AFAIK, GHC can still emit C - at least the `-C` option is still there...

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with [MATLAB/Simulink](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/index.html) (you can choose C or C++ but C is more often use at least if the target is embedded).

Another example is [ArgoUML](http://argouml-cpp.tigris.org/)  (open source UML modeling tool).

Answer (score 2):

Automatic code generation is common among design tools. For instance, you specify your design with UML, Statecharts or both and code is generated. You only have to fill in placeholders for implementing methods.

Examples of such tools are [Rhapsody](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/rhapsody/) and [Topcased](http://www.topcased.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Another example: the [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/) probabilistic programming language compiles to C++ which is then compiled.